# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 | MongoDB > Express > React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm using a MongoDB, Node, Express and React.js. I'm not able to receive data from my node.js server to my react.js client. This is the error I have: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`. I know its a very common error but none of the solutions I found seems relevant for my context.

Here's the package.json line where my proxy is initialized:

`"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",`

Here's my express routing:

```
  app.get('/main-data', (req, res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(connectionURL, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    }, (error, client) => {
      if(error){
        return console.log("Unable to connect to the db.");
      }
      const db = client.db(databaseName);

        db.collection("metadata_from_bot")
        .find()
        .toArray((error, data) => {
          console.log(data);
          res.json(data);
        });
    })
    res.json({hello: "world"})
})
```

Here's my react fetch:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/main-data')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
  }
```

When I go to `http://localhost:5000/main-data`, I receive the following output:

[image]

When I inspect the network tab, here's what I have: `Status Code: 304 Not Modified`.

[image]

However, when I click on the link (http://localhost:3000/main-data) in the network-tab, I get the error.

[image]

The data should be set to the state but now I'm not able to receive it in JSON format.

Comment: The error points to the data coming from `/main-data` likely being HTML - check the network tab in chrome to see the raw response (I'm not familiar with the formatted json view in your screenshot - is that from a chrome extension or the raw output?)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! I forgot adding this to my post (will edit now) but when I see the network tab of my browser, here's what I have `Status Code: 304 Not Modified`. However when I click on the link and access http://localhost:3000/main-data, I have this error (`Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`) showing.

Comment: What do you see in the response section in the network tab (on the right by default once you select the request)?

Comment: Oh I see. I see the index.html file of my react app. It means that the data being sent is in HTML. I means also that my route is not being served as expected.

Comment: `res.json()`, we do not have `.json()` method in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but shouldn't you use host in `fetch`

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/main-data')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
  }
```

Comment: This works perfectly. How do I make this work on production mode?

Comment: I use https://github.com/axios/axios which supports baseURL, you should add a prefix to all of the api calls, in production mode you will compile react to bundled js and css then serve using the express server it self so both will be in same host and port, could you mark the question as the right answer please

Comment: Thank you Anas, I'll use axios next time then.